# How do I convert this object to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I convert `testObj` to an array?

```
function MinEvent(event, width, left){
  this.start = event.start;
  this.end = event.end;
  this.width = width;
  this.top = event.start;
  this.left = left;
}

var testObj = {};
for (var j=0; j<eventLists.length; j++) {
  var eve = eventLists[j];
  var event = new MinEvent(eventList[j], width, left);
  testObj[eve.id] = event;
}
```

Comment: All JavaScript objects are basically associative arrays.  Your code as written should work (Assuming `new Event` is supposed to be `new MinEvent` and `eventLists` is initialized to something sane).

Comment: If you want `testObj` to be a true array, you need to tell us how you want its properties converted.  Maybe it would help if you tell us what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: If I am not wrong, if I keep testObj as an object instead of a true array, i wouldn't know it's length. Right?

Comment: @priyank.mp: right. However if you simply switch `{}` to `[]` you cannot rely on `.length` either: string keys don't affect `.length`, and numeric keys simply bump `.length` to the highest index `+1`. In other words, you should answer @Douglas' question...

Comment: Once I get testObj, I will go through each element, and then I will generate some html code based on the values - start, end, width,top and left.Ex: <div style="top:val1;left:val2;width:val3">test</div>. I will have to sort this array based on start value(testObj[id].start) before I generate an html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically every object in javascript can be treated like an array. Your code should work as-is.

But either way, looking at your code, why not define `testObj` as `var testObj = [];`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.  JavaScript objects are actually the same as an associative array already.  You could access all of its properties and methods like this:

```
for(prop in obj) {
    alert(prop + ” value : ”+ obj[prop];
}
```

Maybe it would help if you told us what you wanted to do once you converted the object inot an array (and what you want the result to look like).

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `testObj` as an array initially you don't need to convert it.

```
//declare the array
var testObj = new Array();
```

or

```
//declare the array
var testObj = [];
```

Index based access should work for either of these. I.e.

```
testObj[0] = "someval";
```

etc.

Comment: LOL why people downed every answer to this question is beyond me. They're all valid, including mine. It's a simple javascript array. It's like grade school around here. Oh me! me! me! I had my hand up first ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = []
for( var prop in testObj )
{
    array.push( testObj[prop] );
}
```

Is this what you want?